# How to retrieve last logon/logoff time in Active Directory (ADAM)?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to write code (C# or Java) to retrieve user logon/logoff information from ADAM, but i'm not sure where to start or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `lastLogonTimeStamp` attribute in AD that will give you this information. However to have this attribute your domain must be at least Windows Server 2003 Domain Functional Level. Just because you have 2003 DC's, don't assume that your DFL has been raised to that level if you are having problems getting this attribute.

Sam

Comment: Is there a way to get the IP address of the logged in users in AD?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are is a attribute called lastLogon, but i dont remember ever seeing one for logoff time

Comment: You may prefer to look at [`lastLogonTimeStamp`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx) as `lastLogon` is not replicated.